# HttpClientHandler does not contain a definition for DefaultProxyCredentials

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the following code to get data from an API using .Net Core 2.0.

```
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials })
        {
            handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            }
        }
```

However, I need to convert the project to .Net framework 4.6.1 and there is no DefaultProxyCredentials property in .Net Framework 4.6.1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.defaultproxycredentials

What is the equivalent of DefaultProxyCredentials in .Net framework 4.6.1 (without using a config file)?

Update: I tried changing the code to the following:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy})
{
}
```

It works but randomly throws 407 - "Proxy Authentication Required" error.

Comment: it looks like it was added to .net 4.8, before that it was done in web config :/

Comment: The CredentialCache is in the user temporary folder under Internet Options.  It can be set by the IE Options in your browser.  The code posted is using DefaultCredentials.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d9607092-c5ff-4019-883c-c88506d699c5/difference-between-defaultnetworkcredentials-and-defaultcredentials?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: @terribletp - yes :( HttpClientHandler.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy works but randomly throws 407.

Comment: @jdweng - I do not have access to client's IE options so have to find a way to set it from code.

Comment: What do you mean by random?  Does it always work with same user on same machine?  Only fails with some users on some machines?

Comment: It works with my user  id, however randomly it throws 407 with the same user id i.e. without any code / user change.

Comment: If you delete your cookies your account probably will also fail.  Or it is the fact that your IE Advance settings are different from other users.  It is NOT random.  The best way of finding issue is to sniffer and compare first request when it works with first request when it does not work.  If it is a cookies you should see in your account a cookie being sent and no cookie in other users.  If it is an IE advance setting then it is setting up a firewall which is blocking and other users you will not see the request.

Comment: The HttpClient in 4.6 is a very old implementation. The best option would be to target 4.7.2 at least, and avoid the .NET Standard dependency hell in the previous versions. 4.7.2 is the only version that's really 2.0 compliant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you targeting 4.6 instead of 4.7.2? This matters and can lead to NuGet dependency hell.

---

It looks like you're using the (very) old HttpClient class included in 4.6 instead of the [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) package. That old implementation doesn't even use the new socket handler. The [HttpClientHandler.DefaultProxyCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.defaultproxycredentials?view=netframework-4.7.1) property was added in .NET 4.7.1.

- The best option is probably to target the latest .NET version, or at least 4.7.1 and use the same code you do now. Better yet, target 4.7.2 to avoid the dependency shim hell explained in the next option.
- You could just add the package. It's the same .NET Standard 2.0 package used in .NET Core projects. The downside to that is that 4.6.1 is *not* really .NET Standard 2.0 compatible and requires *several* compatibility libraries. Upgrading can easily lead to dependency hell as versions conflict with one another. The .NET team [admitted that trying to retrofit .NET Standard 2.0 compliance was a bad idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

> While NuGet considers .NET Framework 4.6.1 as supporting .NET Standard 1.5 through 2.0, there are several issues with consuming .NET Standard libraries that were built for those versions from .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects. For .NET Framework projects that need to use such libraries, we recommend that you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher.

Been there. Have the production crash reports to prove it. And the premium 1 day upgrade experience of *removing* all previous shims to get rid of version conflicts. `Several issues` indeed

- Set the Credentials property of the default proxy with

```
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to upgrade the .Net framework. However, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; seems to have fixed the 407 issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ICredentials interface in the HttpClientHandler called Credentials. So:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() 
{ Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials }) {}
```